# How to Run typescript when component is in view?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

In my Angular single-page app, I don't have any routing, but rather all components are rendered one below the other (each filling the screen).
The menu component is via CSS position: fixed; always at the top of the screen.

something like this:

```html
<app-hmenu></app-hmenu>
<app-comp1></app-comp1>
<app-comp2></app-comp2>
<app-comp3></app-comp3>
```

```
 ┌─────────────────────┐             
 │                     │             
 │     Comp 1          │             
 │                     │             
 │                     │             
 │                     │             
 │                     │             
┌┼─────────────────────┼┐            
│┼─────────────────────┼│ ◄─ viewport
││                     ││            
││     Comp 2          ││            
││                     ││            
││                     ││            
││                     ││            
││                     ││            
└┼─────────────────────┼┘            
 ├─────────────────────┤             
 │                     │             
 │     Comp 3          │             
 │                     │             
 │                     │             
 │                     │             
 │                     │             
 │                     │             
 └─────────────────────┘
```

Now I would like to assign different styles to the menu as soon as I have scrolled down far enough, i.e. when the other components are in the user's field of vision.

So how can I execute a specific typescript method in the HMenu component when the menu is hovering over, for example, Comp2, i.e. Comp2 is mostly visible in the viewport?